# como seleccionar una clase en css sin importar el sufijo?

Tags: css, wordpress

actualmente trabajando un proyecto de wordpress utilicé un plugin para crear tabs, entonces generé css para customizarlo, pero al crear otro tab (con id diferente) pude notar que no cogió el css que ya había creado, me di cuenta que a algunas clases el plugin les añade el id como sufijo.. ejemplo

```
.oxi-tabs-wrapper-3{
/*css aqui*/ }
```

Donde el 3 es el id del tab, mi pregunta es, como puedo hacer referencia a esa clase desde css sin importar el sufijo? y como se pueden generar clases de manera automática?

Comment: El 3 está puesto como sufijo (al final) y no como prefijo, pues tendría que aparecer al principio. Por otro lado, cuando dices _hacer referencia_, creo que debieras aclarar desde dónde le quieres hacer referencia, porque supongo que no será lo mismo hacer referencia desde javascript, que desde CSS o js con jQuery

Comment: quiero hacer referencia desde css

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un selector que busque que el elemento contenga una clase con el string que buscas, esto lo puedes lograr usando este selector

`[class*='oxi-tabs-wrapper']`

Este permite buscar en el atributo `class` un string que haga match con `oxi-tabs-wrapper`, un ejemplo del match:

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: red;
}


[class*='oxi-tabs-wrapper'] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box oxi-tabs-wrapper-1"></div>
<div class="box oxi-tabs-wrapper-2"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero al parecer agregaste un nuevo tab o tabs y querés darle tu propio estilo CSS sobre el estilo que ya está definido por bootstrap. Eso es lo que entiendo.
Si es así, es posible y es fácil. Primero, en `head`, agrega tu `link` de estilo CSS después de **bootstrap.min.css**, luego, en el HTML5, en tu etiqueta **tab**, en `class` al final de todos los atributos (al final de **oxi-tabs-wrapper-3**); como por ejemplo:

```
<div class="oxi-tabs-wrapper-3 miEstilo">
```

Comment: Creo que no me explique... lo que quiero es poder hacer lo siguiente .oxi-tabs-wrapper-n{ color: blue;} Donde "n" es un número cualquiera

Comment: Para que buscar tantas vueltas? Si tenés acceso a tu panel de control de wordpress *(en mi respuesta me equivoqué y puse bootstrap)*,  abrí tu menú,  apariencia, y luego editor de tema. Ahí ya tenés tu editor de tema para editar lo que quieras. Pero cuidado! No edites mal y que se destruya tu página.